# unresolved import flask visual studio 2019

Tags: python, flask, visual-studio-2019

i just started playing with python on the last version of visual studio 2019. I added a new project flask web project. by adding `

> from flask import Flask`

I get unresolved import flask. what else tool, or modules should I import to my solution? any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding flask env inside of the solution it has been compiled and run in the localhostf